# Chaining functions on a trait

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, nightly-build

I'm trying to make chainable transformations on a trait, and I'm having some issues.

I have a bunch of transformation functions of the form:

```
fn transform<T: MyTrait>(in: T) -> impl MyTrait
```

And I want a function `chain` which will allow me to do

```
let mut val: Box<MyTrait> = ...;
val = chain(val, transform1);
val = chain(val, transform2);
...
```

I have written this function

```
fn chain<T, U, F>(val: Box<T>, f: F) -> Box<MyTrait>
  where T: MyTrait,
        U: MyTrait,
        F: FnOnce(T) -> U {
  Box::new(f(*val))
}
```

But when I compile, the borrow checker tells me that the type parameter U doesn't live long enough. I'm pretty sure my trait bounds are what I want, and I've tried various things with lifetime specifiers, so I'm stuck :(

P.S. : Is it possible to make the `chain` function generic on `MyTrait`? I don't think it's possible, but we never know...

**EDIT**:

I've added the fix proposed by @chris-emerson in his answer, by as I've said in its comments, I have uncovered another problem which seems unresolvable.

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a519f51db3f43191f354c40e85b79fe1&version=nightly) is a gist of the code, to not clutter this post.

In short, the problem is: the chain function needs to dereference the `Box<T>` object and pass the `T` to the transform function, so `T` must be `Sized`. But the whole point of this function was to allow arbitrary (and unknown at compile-time) `MyTrait` implementations to be used. For example:

```
let mut val: Box<MyTrait> = ...;
//here we can know the type inside the Box
if ... {
  val = chain(val, transform);
}
//but here we don't know anymore
//(its either the original type,
//or the type returned by transform)
```

So this design can't work unless the transform function can take a &T or a &mut T (which it can't, as I need to consume the input to produce the output).

Comment: I'm confused, are `T` and `U` supposed to be different traits?

Comment: @Jsor: Probably, given that `F` is a transformer here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm thinking they actually want to transform between two implementations of the same trait, and then convert it into a boxed trait object.

Comment: @Jsor: Ah sorry; I misread. Given the type of the chain, I think that `T` and `U` are just difference instances of the same trait because the chain itself takes a trait in and returns *the same* trait out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full compiler message is:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `U` may not live long enough
--> <anon>:7:3
  |
7 |   Box::new(f(*val))
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `U: 'static`...
  note:...so that the type `U` will meet its required lifetime bounds
--> <anon>:7:3
  |
7 |   Box::new(f(*val))
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The compiler is saying that it needs `U` to live for the `'static` lifetime; what this really means is that any references inside it need to be valid for that lifetime, since the `Box` can live forever (as far as the compiler knows here).

So the fix is simple: add `'static` to `U`'s bounds:

```
fn chain<T, U, F>(val: Box<T>, f: F) -> Box<MyTrait>
  where T: MyTrait,
        U: MyTrait + 'static,
        F: FnOnce(T) -> U,
{
    Box::new(f(*val))
}
```

Adding an extra bound `U: 'static` would also be equivalent.

Comment: It might be "quicker" to say `U: MyTrait + 'static,` rather than introduce a second `U` line.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but arbitrarily decided it would be clearer to add the seaprate bound.  I'll add a note.

Comment: I don't think it is clearer as it seems unusual to have a second line describing a type parameter (and thus might not be looked at at first glance)

Comment: Okay, it was this simple ;)

Comment: However, there's another problem now: inside ```chain```, the ```Box``` points to an unsized trait, so I can't pass it to the transform function, and I can't pass a reference to it... I guess I have to ditch the idea entirely and simply and make the transform functions take and return a ```Box<MyTrait>```.

Comment: Do you mean that one or both of `T` and `U` are trait objects instead of concrete types?

Comment: Or is your problem fixed by changing the return value to `Box<U>`?  It would probably help to see the context (perhaps in a new question).

Comment: I've edited the main post with more details on the problem. (If I return Box<U>, then it becomes completely equivalent to `let val = Box::new(...); let val = transform1(val); let val = transform2(val); ...`, so it's useless)